# Smart ways to determine if a search request is an address or a business for use in Google APIS?

Tags: string, google-maps, geocoding, google-local-search

Here is the problem, I have an app with a search bar, the user can input something like "18th Street" or "Starbucks" and it uses the Google Geocoding and Local Search APIs respectively to get results.

I'm wondering is there a smart way to determine whether or not a given input string is an address that needs to be Geocoded, or a business name that needs to use Local Search.

Obviously I could try and handroll something, but I'm wondering if someone has already done this or Google provides such functionality themselves.

Cheers.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't try geocoding everything, and then use Local Search for those that fail with code 602 or 603?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Local Search by default does this and processes Geocodes and business searches. There is some coarseness to it, but I guess that is to be expected

You can change this behaviour by specifying

> mrt?       This optional argument
>   specifies which type of listing the
>   user is interested in. Valid values
>   include:
>
> ```
> * blended - request KML, Local Business Listings, and Geocode results
> * kmlonly - request KML and Geocode results
> * localonly - request Local Business Listings and Geocode results
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind would be a regular expression that looks for a street address, but the important question is how your system would qualify an address.

It's reasonable enough to match something that is going to be fairly consistent in format like a fully qualified street address, but when it's something like "18th Street" how do you know they don't actually want a restaurant called "18th Street"? What you might consider is a regular expression that loosely attempts to match a street address and, if it finds one, call the Geocoding. In the event no results are returned by Geocoding, then default to a Local Search.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, as it turns out Local Search by default does this and processes Geocodes and business searches. There is some coarseness to it, but I guess that is to be expected.